# Helm template: How raise exception in in helm function?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

In helm templating, I want to raise an error if the condition is not matched.

Code:

```
{{- if eq .Values.key "desiredValue" }}
{{- .Value.key }}
{{- else }}
{{- raise "value for .Values.key is not as expected" }}
{{- end }}
```

Where :

**raise**: is a function which will fail the helm possess and will display error **value for .Values.key is not as expected**.

How to achieve the functionality of `raise` as illustrated in code above in helm templating?

One way to achieve this is:

```
{{- if eq .Values.key "desiredValue" }}
{{- .Value.key }}
{{- else }}
{{- required "value for .Values.key is not as expected" "" }}
{{- end }}
```

But I want to know if there are any other elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 18):

The Sprig support library includes a [`fail`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/flow_control.html) function that has the same semantics as your proposed `raise`.

```
{{- if ne .Values.key "desiredValue" }}
{{- fail "value for .Values.key is not as expected" }}
{{- end }}
```